# Multiple marketing attribution with keras

Tags: python, keras

I have trials participating in three marketing campaigns `A, B, C` several times. Let's say marketing events are independent and each has its own conversion probability p_A, p_B, p_C.

```
campaigns = {
    'A': 0.1, # name, conversion probability
    'B': 0.2,
    'C': 0.4,
}
```

Some users converted into paid accounts.
I have a dataframe when each row is a user and column is a number of times the user has been exposed to a particular campaign.

```
   A  B  C  converted
0  3  1  0       True
1  0  0  1      False
2  3  1  1       True
3  1  3  2      False
4  1  0  0      False
```

In this case, total conversion probability will be:

```
1 - (1 - p_A) ** A * (1 - p_B) ** B * (1 - p_C) ** C
```

What is the best way to estimate original `p_A, p_B, p_C`?

I am looking for some keras solution, but I am not sure how to set custom power/exponential layers. I think the model should look like:

```
1 - (w_1 ** A) * (w_2 ** B) * (w_3 ** C) ~ predicted probability
```

but there is neither standard power, no product layers in keras.

Python code to generate full example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(4)
n = 1000
data = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(n), columns=['prob'])

campaigns = {
    'A': 0.1,
    'B': 0.2,
    'C': 0.4,
}

for campaign, conversion in campaigns.items():
    data[campaign] = np.random.geometric(1 / (1 + .5), n) - 1
    data['prob'] = 1 - (1 - data['prob']) * (1 - conversion) ** data[campaign]

data['converted'] = np.random.rand(n) < data['prob']
print(data.head())   

       prob  A  B  C  converted
0  0.416800  3  1  0       True
1  0.400000  0  0  1      False
2  0.650080  3  1  1       True
3  0.834112  1  3  2      False
4  0.100000  1  0  0      False
```

Comment: what does each row mean in your dataset? does it represent a user?

Comment: and what does the values of A, B and C represent? number of times that user was exposed to that marketing campaign?

Comment: Each row is a user and a number of times he participated in campaign A, B and C

Comment: 1 - (1 - p_a) ** A * (1 - p_b) ** B * (1 - p_c) ** C
I'm not getting this formula.

Comment: User will not convert if all the campaigns are not successful. It means that hi will convert if any of them are successful

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I rewrote the question in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
import numpy as np
from keras.backend import pow

class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                      shape=(input_shape[1], self.output_dim),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        A,B,C,w_1,w_2,w_3=x[0],x[1],x[2],self.kernel[0],self.kernel[1],self.kernel[2]
        return  (1-(pow(w_1, A))*(pow(w_2, B))*(pow(w_3, C)))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

This layer represents this formula:

```
1 - (w_1 ** A) * (w_2 ** B) * (w_3 ** C) ~ predicted probability
```

https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/
This is the template I used, Only thing that I had to change was call function.